# PyUSB backend not accessible

Tags: python, pyusb

hey i am trying to run the simple script available in the tutorial;. the usb is getting imported but when i try to search the device i get the following error,please help

```
>>> dev=usb.core.find()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 819, in find
    raise ValueError('No backend available')
ValueError: No backend available
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13773132/1778421

Answer (score 11):

You need to install libusb-1.0, libusb-0.1, or openusb as a backend to pyusb.  Is this a Windows machine?

If so, you can download a simple installer here: http://www.craftedge.com/products/libusb.html

Comment: Having the same issue on a Mac (Yosemite 10.10.1), libusb-1.0 is installed... any ideas?

Comment: @user1088166 try these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756032/pyusb-valueerror-no-backend-available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189194/how-do-i-switch-backends-in-libusb-for-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853634/how-to-set-up-libusb-on-mac-os-x