# Pyusb on windows - no backend available

Tags: python, windows-7, libusb, pyusb

I'm trying to have my Python application interface with an NFC device via USB.
The best option seems to be [PyUSB](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb), but I can't get it to connect to the libusb backend.
I keep getting

> ValueError: No backend available

I've looked at the stack trace, and found that `usb/backend/libusb10.py` (which is part of pyusb) is trying to load `libusb-1.0.dll` to use as the backend, but it can't find it. It's not that it's not in my path, it's not on my computer at all!

I have installed [libusb-win32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/), but the resulting directory only seems to include libusb0.dll. Where is libusb-1.0.dll???!

I would love to know either where to get that dll, or even a different suggestion to get PyUSB to work on Windows 7.

Answer (score 26):

Download and install [libusb-win32-devel-filter-1.2.6.0.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/files/libusb-win32-releases/1.2.6.0/). It should work.

Comment: libusb-win32 from sourceforge is very outdated, last release in 2012. If you're using anything recent consider downloading from https://libusb.info/

Answer (score 10):

2021 and the problem still occurs on Windows (Windows 10). I solved it by installing `pyusb` and `libusb` **and adding libusb path to Windows environment**:

1. `pip install pyusb`
2. `pip install libusb`
3. `libusb-1.0.dll` will be automatically added to:

`\venv\Lib\site-packages\libusb\_platform\_windows\x64`
and
`\venv\Lib\site-packages\libusb\_platform\_windows\x32`

4. Now just add those paths (the full path) to Windows Path **and restart CMD / PyCharm**.

Comment: Have installed these packages and included the paths in Path Env Variable on my Win-10 machine. However, running this line of code still throws the "No Backenderror" import usb
for dev in usb.core.find(find_all=True):
    print("Devices - " + dev)

Comment: @AshwinKumar - Are you sure you installed the correct libraries? There's a `pylibusb` which is not what you should install. Also, make sure to restart PyCharm / CMD after updating Windows Path (it won't work otherwise). Maybe try to start from a clean venv

Comment: I have installed the package you are mentioning. Here is the screenshot showing same - https://file.io/EYaucUUluN9e Have uploade the screenshot of my code here https://file.io/MyORGzN3zJF0 Please let me know if I am missing anything. You have to excuse any basic mistake - I am not an active developer :-)

Comment: @AshwinKumar - I can't open the links, either uploda to Imgur, or try to debug it by setting a breakpoint in `libloader.py` (located in `/venv/Lib/site-packages/usb`) on line 92 `for candidate in candidates`, continue to the 2nd iteration until `candidate == libusb-1.0`, step in to `find_library()`, and continue until `directory` is the path you added to the Path, then see what `os.path.isfile(fname)` returns

Comment: @AlaaM. thanks, this helped. However, I can't believe that the original idea is to add everything to the Windows PATH environment variable. Well, if you just `pip install libusb` and Python doesn't find it, my question would be: where does Python actually look for it? Do you or anyone know?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue recently trying to talk to a USB device I am developing.  I scoured the web looking for libusb-1.0.dll's and had no luck.  I found source code, but nothing built and ready to install.  I ended up installing the libusb-win32 binaries, which is the libusb0.dll.

PyUSB will search for libusb-1.0, libusb0, and openUSB backends.

libusb0.dll was already on my system, but something was still not set up right, do PyUSB was not working.

I followed the directions [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki) to download and install the driver using the GUI tools provided to install the filter driver, and the INF wizard.  Note, it didn't work until I ran the INF wizard.

I'm pretty new to programming and I've found the lack of clear documentation/examples to string this all together rather frustrating.

Comment: Yes, run the inf-wizard and select your device to start.

Comment: @jonincanada  it seems that i have run into the same problem as Garrett Hyde. but the difference is that i have downloaded and unzipped the file(libusb1.0.20),then copied a dll file, specifically(libusb-1.0.dll) and copied it to system 32; then i copied libusb-1.lib to python34/Lib. and still there is 'no backend' error,so can you help me solve the problem?

Comment: Adafruit has a good guide on getting pyusb working on Windows: 
https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-any-computer-with-ft232h/windows

Comment: that did the trick. Thanks a lot @jjz

Answer (score 8):

There's a simpler solution.

Download and unpack to C:\PATH the libusb-1.0.20 from [download link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/files/libusb-1.0/libusb-1.0.20/libusb-1.0.20.7z/download)

Then try this line:

> ```
> backend = usb.backend.libusb1.get_backend(find_library=lambda x: "C:\\PATH\\libusb-1.0.20\\MS32\\dll\\libusb-1.0.dll")
> usb_devices = usb.core.find(backend=backend, find_all=True)
> ```

Depending on your system, try either MS64 or MS32 version of the .dll

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import usb.backend.libusb1

from infi.devicemanager import DeviceManager

dm = DeviceManager()
devices = dm.all_devices
for d in devices:
    try:
        print(f'{d.friendly_name} : address: {d.address}, bus: {d.bus_number}, location: {d.location}')
    except Exception:
        pass


backend = usb.backend.libusb1.get_backend(find_library=lambda x: "C:\\libusb-1.0.20\\MS32\\dll\\libusb-1.0.dll")
usb_devices = usb.core.find(backend=backend, find_all=True)


def enumerate_usb():  # I use a simple function that scans all known USB connections and saves their info in the file
    with open("EnumerateUSBLog.txt", "w") as wf:
        for i, d in enumerate(usb_devices):
            try:
                wf.write(f"USB Device number {i}:\n")
                wf.write(d._get_full_descriptor_str() + "\n")
                wf.write(d.get_active_configuration() + "\n")
                wf.write("\n")
            except NotImplementedError:
                wf.write(f"Device number {i} is busy.\n\n")
            except usb.core.USBError:
                wf.write(f"Device number {i} is either disconnected or not found.\n\n")
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using Python 2.6.5, `libusb-win32-device.bin-0.1.12.1` and `pyusb-1.0.0-a0` on a windows XP system and kept receiving `ValueError: No backend available`.

Since there wasn't any real help on the web for this problem I spent a lot of time finding that `ctypes util.py` uses the `Path` variable to find the library file.  My `path` did not include `windows\system32` and `PYUSB` didn't find the library.  I updated the `path` variable and now the USB is working.

Comment: Given that this is about XP (and the OP was asking Re: Windows 7) this might have been better as a comment.

Comment: I added the current folder to the `PATH`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Windows 10, both Python 2.7.16 and Python 3.7.2.  I installed libusb (through `python -m pip install libusb` ) but the error message remained. Also, the advice above about installing libusb-win32 did not work for me; neither of the 2 links (original post and @beebek's answer) existed.

What **did** work, however, is the comment by @user1495323 : I copied `libusb-1.0.dll` from 
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\libusb\_platform\_windows\x64\`
to `C:\Windows\System32\`

Comment: This works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Had some problems with backendnotavailable at 2022 when I install **pyusb** and **libusb** on my **Windows x64**.

---

I've found a way to solve it reading -> [Github solve explaining](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/faq.rst)

To solve, ***first*** you need copy path to libusb-1.0.dll *(..\envs<your_env_name>\Lib\site-packages\libusb_platform_windows\x64)* at system's PATH variable.

***Secondly*** restart IDE.

***Third*** try to get_backend use usb.backend:

```
import usb.core
from usb.backend import libusb1

# it should find libusb-1.0.dll at our path variable
back = libusb1.get_backend()
print(type(back))  # return: <class 'usb.backend.libusb1._LibUSB'>

dev = usb.core.find(backend=back)
print(type(dev))  # return: <class 'usb.core.Device'>

# flag 'find_all=True' would return generator
# reprecent connected usb devices

dev_list = usb.core.find(find_all=True, backend=back)
print(type(dev_list)) # return: <class 'generator'>
```

If back is a `NoneType`, that means `get_backend()` hasn't found libusb-1.0.dll or found the wrong usblib (and that was my problem - I copied atPATH variable path to _x86 file, on my x64 machine).

---

Another way to solve it -> copy libusb-1.0.dll from *(.._x64\libusb-1.0.dll)* to *(C:\Windows\System32)*.

Answer (score 2):

1. download the latest libusb
   [Download libusb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/files/libusb-1.0/libusb-1.0.20/libusb-1.0.20.7z/download)
2. 

Copy *MS32\dll\libusb-1.0.dll* to *C:\Windows\SysWOW64*

Copy *MS64\dll\libusb-1.0.dll* to *C:\Windows\System32*

3.

```
pip install libusb
```

4. 

Copy *MS32\dll\libusb-1.0.dll* to *C:\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\libusb_platform_windows\x86*

Copy *MS64\dll\libusb-1.0.dll* to *C:\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\libusb_platform_windows\x64*

This method works for me.

Answer (score 1):

"There are two versions of the libusb API: the current `libusb-1.0` API, and its legacy predecessor `libusb-0.1`." (http://www.libusb.org/) "`libusb-win32` is a port of the USB library ​`libusb-0.1` to the Microsoft Windows operating systems". "Download the latest release tarball" from the [same page](http://www.libusb.org/) (`1.0.9` is the current version) to have `libusb-1.0` equivalent, you'll find a folder `Win32`, where you'll find your `libusb-1.0.dll` to play with! You can even build it: http://www.libusb.org/wiki/windows_backend.

**EDIT**
You have to build it (download from/ http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/files/libusb-1.0/) since the tarball is from 2012, while the latest sources are from 2014-06-15.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mix from multiple answers and here a ready-to-use solution for Windows x64 bit:

- Run:

  ```
  pip install pyusb
  pip install libusb
  ```
- Do:

  ```
  import usb.backend.libusb1
  backend = usb.backend.libusb1.get_backend(find_library=lambda x: r"C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\libusb\_platform\_windows\x64\libusb-1.0.dll")  # adapt to your path
  usb_devices = usb.core.find(backend=backend, find_all=True)
  for usb_device in usb_devices:
      print(usb_device)
  ```

Done!

Comment: You might consider `libusb.__file__.replace('__init__.py', r'_platform\_windows\x64\libusb-1.0.dll')` to avoid the hard-coded path to the Python installation directory. (This still assumes that the location of the dll within the `libusb` package is fixed though.)

Comment: Alternatively: `next(pathlib.Path(libusb.__file__).parent.rglob('x64/libusb-1.0.dll'))`, which searches for a file `x64/libusb-1.0.dll` inside the `libusb` directory. Free free to incorporate this into your answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to your NFC device via USB using PYUSB, you will need to install the backend for that device. I do not think there is any backend for any device other than a libusb device.

To build a backend. You will need to know the driver (.sys file) for your device, so you could write a wrapper DLL to expose functionalities in the device. Your DLL would have to have a method to find device based on PID & VID, another method to open device and another method to send data and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case:

I haven't tried this on Windows but I had to set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH path to circumvent this error on the Macintosh.

> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib

Discussion on whether or not to set this variable is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/282450/where-do-i-set-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-is-it-a-good-idea).

Answer (score 0):

The libusb backend is initialized by the python script in /usb path,by loading the binary DLL from Windows PATH,if it's missed or installed by the zadig's dummy DLL,it will complained about this.Because the DLL installed by zadig doesn't exports any symbol to outside wolrd(dummy one I guess)