# PyUSB - No Backend Available (Windows 10) Any solutions?

Tags: python, pyusb

I'm using Windows 10, and trying to use pyusb. I'm facing this *Backend error*, I've tried searching for solutions, but haven't found one yet.

Please, let me know, if there's a way to deal with this.

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: i think it means you need libusb ... or openusb. see https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/usb/core.py#L1263

Comment: Hi Joran,
I've installed https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/ on Windows 10. But I'm still facing the same issue. No Backend Available. Any idea/clue?

Comment: are you using python32? you need to get the version that matches your python version... also post your full traceback ... (preferably not as an image)

Comment: I closed as a duplicate after I verified that the proposed solution worked for me (specifically this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31332121/541038 )

Comment: Here you go. 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/saxendi/PycharmProjects/untitled7/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    dev = usb.core.find()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 1263, in find
    raise NoBackendError('No backend available')
usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available