# How can I print images with a thermal printer and python-escpos under Windows 11?

Tags: python-3.x, escpos

I can not print images with my thermal printer under Microsoft Windows OS, with python and python-escpos.

- Python version: 3.11.3
- Python-escpos version: 3.0a9
- OS: Windows 11 22H2
- Thermal printer: OCPP-58E-U

Sample code:

```
from escpos.printer import Usb

p = Usb(0x0456, 0x0808, in_ep=0x81, out_ep=0x03, profile='POS-5890')
p.charcode(code='AUTO')
p.codepage = 'WPC1250'
p.text('Image printing...')
p.image('test.png')
p.close()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Source Code\reward_printer\rewards.py", line 76, in print_something
    p.image('test.png')
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\escpos\escpos.py", line 210, in image
    self._raw(header + im.to_raster_format())
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\escpos\printer.py", line 130, in _raw
    self.device.write(self.out_ep, msg, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 989, in write
    return fn(
           ^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 837, in bulk_write
    return self.__write(self.lib.libusb_bulk_transfer,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 938, in __write
    _check(retval)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 604, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 32] Pipe error
```

**Remarks**

- Usb id and vendor are correct. The printer prints the text before the image.
- The image exists and has no errors. I can open it fine with any image editor.
- Strangly only a portion of the image prints before the scripts halts with the error message
  [image: Sample printing]
- [Edit] File formats that I used ( and produce the same error ): PNG, BMP, TIFF, GIF ( static not animated )

**Assumption**

Is this some kind of usb buffer error?

**Question**

How can I fix it please?

**P.S.**

Thank you in advance for your precious time!

Comment: try printing a bitmap image instead of a png image

Comment: also try a tiff image... obviously convert your png to both bitmap (bmp) and png (png)

use [this](https://convertio.co/png-bmp/) to do the conversions

Comment: I edited my question to include file formats for the image that I used and produce the same error... Sadly nor BMP or TIFF or GIF are working...

Comment: read [this](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0a8/api/image.html)

Comment: I did. I fail to see how it can help me... I am using the official example from the documentation of python-escpos. I assume it is a problem with Microsoft Windows or my installation setup and not the code it self. But I am *assuming* that's why I am asking here!

Comment: Maybe the printer's receive buffer is small. How about dividing the image into multiple vertical sizes that could be printed in the question, creating multiple files, and requesting them to be printed one after the other? Like these articles, it may not be a problem with how to use ESCPOS itself, but a problem related to USB or hardware timing. [How to solve "control message failed, win error: A device which does not exist ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60553035/9014308), [usb.core.USBError: \[Errno 32\] Pipe error after some time #415](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/discussions/415)

Comment: I just tested the printer under Linux with the exact same script... It works *fine* ! So I am ( still ) assuming something is wrong with my installation setup or Microsoft Windows it self or ...maybe the actual python-escpos source code not handling usb connections correctly on windows? Still searching or waiting for an an answer.