# How do I switch backends in libusb for python?

Tags: python, backend

I am using pyusb and according to the docs it runs on any one of three backends.  libusb01 libusb10 and openusb.  I have all three backends installed.  How can I tell which backend it is using and how can I switch to a different one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by looking inside the usb.core source file.

You do it by importing the backend and then setting a parameter inside the find method of usb.core. Like so:

```
import usb.backend.libusb1 as libusb1
import usb.backend.libusb0 as libusb0
import usb.backend.openusb as openusb
```

and then any one of:

```
devices = usb.core.find(find_all=1, backend=libusb1.get_backend() )    
devices = usb.core.find(find_all=1, backend=libusb0.get_backend() )    
devices = usb.core.find(find_all=1, backend=openusb.get_backend() )
```

This assumes you are using pyusb-1.0.0a3. For 1.0.0a2 the libs are called libusb10, libusb01 and openusb. Of course, you'd only need to import the one you want.