# pyusb ValueError: No backend available bar code scanner

Tags: python, libusb, pyusb, libusb-win32

I'am trying to take over an barcode scanner using pyusb and pyusb-keyboard-a-like.
I have a system running win7. I have installed usb drivers with `libusb-win32` both filter and inf-wizard.
my code looks like this:

```
from keyboard_alike import reader


class BarCodeReader(reader.Reader):

pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    reader = BarCodeReader(0x0c2e, 0x0b41, 84, 6, should_reset=False)
    reader.initialize()
    print(reader.read().strip())
    reader.disconnect()
```

and gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Downloads\pyusb-keyboard-alike-master\pyusb-keyboard-alike-master\lindy_bar_code_scanner.py", line 14, in <module>
reader.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Downloads\pyusb-keyboard-alike-master\pyusb-keyboard-alike-master\keyboard_alike\reader.py", line 37, in initialize
self._device = usb.core.find(idVendor=self.vendor_id, idProduct=self.product_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 846, in find
raise ValueError('No backend available')
 ValueError: No backend available
```

how can i  resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a backend, namely a `libusb` implementation, either by `libusb-0.1`, by `libusb-1.0` or by `openusb` (as seen in the folder `pyusb-<version>\usb\backend`). In your case, it is `libusb-0.1` since you used `libusb-win32`, consequently the python script must be able to find `libusb0.dll` in the libraries path. I provided a solution for this typical problem here: [PyUSB ValueError: No backend available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756032/pyusb-valueerror-no-backend-available).