# Pyusb on windows 8.1 - no backend available - how to install libusb?

Tags: python, usb, pyinstaller, pyusb

Working on pyinstaller 3.1, python 2.7.9, and tkinter.

Try to use pyusb instead of pyserial, but no backend available. Looking into [Pyusb on windows - no backend available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773132/pyusb-on-windows-no-backend-available), [PyUSB ValueError: No backend available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756032/pyusb-valueerror-no-backend-available?lq=1), [USB interface in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174671/usb-interface-in-python?lq=1), and so on, it seems that I need to install libusb. But when I run "import usb" and "import usb.core" under python, no errors. I have no idea how to install it and how to use it in my project, how to tell my project where libusb is.

what I did:

(1) download libusb-win32-bin v1.2.6.0 (01/17/2012)

(2) x86\libusb0_x86.dll renamed to libusb0.dll

(3) On 64 bit, put it to Windows\syswow64\libusb0.dll.
    On 32 bit, Installs to Windows\system32\libusb0.dll.

Still not working...

By the way, I would like to finish one standalone python-based windows app. I do not hope others to install libusb to run my app. What to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I downloaded latest libusb windows binaries from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/files/libusb-1.0/libusb-1.0.20/libusb-1.0.20.7z/download
then I copied libusb1.dll according to this: when you are on 64-bit Windows,
MS64\dll\libusb-1.0.dll must be copied into C:\Windows\System32 and
(for running 32-bit applications that use libusb)
MS32\dll\libusb-1.0.dll must be copied into C:\Windows\SysWOW64.
and then I copied libusb1.lib from binaries to lib dir in python directory and now pyusb works for me. hope it helps.

Comment: small correction. libusb lib file can be found at ..\libusb-1.0.20\MS64\static\libusb-1.0.lib for x64

Comment: are you using 32-bit or 64-bit python?  does it matter?

Comment: I am using 64 bit. but I dont think it should matter.Of curse if you use 32 bit make sure you copy the right files.

Comment: It works for me with Win10 and Python2.7(32-Bit) and Python3.5(32-Bit) and Python3.5(64-Bit)

Comment: on the last part to make it precise: for x64 copy ..\libusb-1.0.20\MS64\static\libusb-1.0.lib to C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\libs if you installed Python in default dir

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy and paste the libusb-1.0.lib file to your C drive, just do the things with libusb-1.0.dll file. It works for me.