# libusb, pyusb and python-escpos on a windows machine

Tags: python, libusb, pyusb, escpos, escp

I am trying to work with Epson POS TM-82 printer on windows 7 (64 bit). I have installed the printer's driver. I have python 2.7.15 (64 bit) installed. To work with python I am using this package, [python-escpos](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos).

After I have installed python-escpos, and try to run as [documented](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/usage.html#define-your-instance), I am getting an error:

```
from escpos.printer import Usb
Usb(0x04b8, 0x0e11)
```

> usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available

1. After some more digging, I found this [wiki](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/wiki/Windows), according to this I need to Use the most recent version of Zadig, an Automated Driver Installer GUI application for WinUSB, libusb-win32 and libusbK.

   So, I downloaded Zadig; from the drop-down menu selected TM-82, and chose WinUSB to replace the driver and installed the driver succesfully.

   After that again I ran the same python-escpos documented command from above, and got the same error:

   > usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available
2. After some more research I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972145/pyusb-on-windows-8-1-no-backend-available-how-to-install-libusb/34720024#34720024) on stackoverflow. So following the answer, I downloaded the libusb zip file, and copied `libusb-1.0.20_2\MS64\dll\libusb-1.0.lib` to my `C:\Windows\System32`. And finally copied `libusb-1.0.20_2\MS64\static\libusb-1.0.lib` to `C:\Python27\libs\`

   After that again I ran the same python-escpos documented command from above, and this time I got a different error:

   > NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform

What am I missing here? Could you please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here. So, it turns out, the problem was with python-escpos library. I had to remove the following from the [printer.py](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos/blob/development/src/escpos/printer.py) (python module of that library):

```
try:
    check_driver = self.device.is_kernel_driver_active(0)
except NotImplementedError:
    pass
if check_driver is None or check_driver:
    try:
        self.device.detach_kernel_driver(0)
    except usb.core.USBError as e:
        if check_driver is not None:
            print("Could not detatch kernel driver: {0}".format(str(e)))
```

The details can be found on my blog on [Medium](https://medium.com/@nyorikakar/printing-with-python-and-epson-pos-printer-fbd17e127b6c).

Comment: Getting this error still `NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform`.