# Installing libusb from MacPorts on MAC OS X 10.9.3 and Xcode for the purpose of using Python and PyUSB

Tags: python, xcode, macos, libusb, pyusb

I installed [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) and with that installed [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb). Then I downloaded [PyUSB](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyusb/) and tried to excute the PyUSB sample code with Python's [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29) and Apple [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode). However, I got the same result with both. It failed to find libusb (it's called beckend in PyUSB code which loooks for them). This is the sample code I used to run PyUSB:

```
import usb.core
import usb.utils
dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
print dev
```

And this is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mynewpyproj.py", line 7, in <module>
dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/usb/core.py", line 864, in find
raise ValueError('No backend available')
ValueError: No backend available
```

I tried to use this post and somehow link Xcode and libusb together, but I couldn't do it - I couldn't figure how to. I used Stack Overflow question *[How to set up libusb on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853634)* as a reference. I ran it on Linux [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) and everything work great, but on Mac OS X it's much more difficult purpose to setup PyUSB in Mac OS X and with that to get information about USB devices like device class, speed, name, etc.

Also, I would like to get the port number from PyUSB. How do I get it with PyUSB? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted macports and installed Homebrew, and libusb through homebrew and now it works.